# NextJs 13 - module not found for @aws-sdk packages

Tags: javascript, next.js

i have fresh project installed by create-next-app. I'm using API handlers for api calls and next js give me errors for @aws-sdk packages. I'm sure 100% i have correct paths. Why?

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb'

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { ddbDocClient } from "@/aws-services/dynamodb/ddbDocClient";

export async function POST(request: Request) {
    try {
        const { email, password } = await request.json();

        if (!email || !password) {
            return NextResponse.json({ // 401
                error: {
                    code: 401,
                    message: "Unauthorized",
                    description: "Email and password are required"
                }
            })
        }
        
        
        const response = await ddbDocClient.get({
            TableName: "USERS",
            Key: {
                email
            }
        });
        
        if (response?.Item?.password === password) {
            return NextResponse.json((response.Item as any)); // 200
        } 
    
        else {
            return NextResponse.json({ // 401
                error: {
                    code: 401,
                    message: "Unauthorized",
                    description: "Invalid email or password"
                }
            })
        }
    } catch (err){
        return NextResponse.json({ // 500
            error: {
                code: 500,
                message: "Internal Server Error",
                description: "An error occurred while authorize user."
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I tried diffrence paths, newset version next

@Edit
My package.json

> {   "name": "test-app",   "version": "0.1.0",   "private": true,
> "scripts": {
> "dev": "next dev",
> "build": "next build",
> "start": "next start",
> "lint": "next lint"   },   "dependencies": {
> "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb": "^3.395.0",
> "@aws-sdk/client-ses": "^3.395.0",
> "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb": "^3.395.0",
> "@types/node": "20.5.0",
> "@types/react": "18.2.20",
> "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
> "autoprefixer": "10.4.15",
> "aws-sdk": "^2.1440.0",
> "eslint": "8.47.0",
> "eslint-config-next": "13.4.17",
> "next": "^13.4.19",
> "next-auth": "^4.23.1",
> "postcss": "8.4.28",
> "react": "18.2.0",
> "react-dom": "18.2.0",
> "tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
> "typescript": "5.1.6"   } }

Error:
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JxfH.png)

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: Can you share your package.json and the exact error?

Comment: Could you share you `tsconfig.json`? Have you specified the `path`correctly to use `@`? I had a similar issue with another npm package, and had to make some configuration for the `next.config.js`too. You can try adding in the `next.config.js` the following: `config.externals = [...config.externals, '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb'];`

Comment: @RobinThomas i shared my package.json and error in topic

Comment: Whats the output of `npm ls @aws-sdk/client-dynamodb`?

Comment: @Benji i have added tsconfig.json in topic. How can i add this property "config.externals" for empty next js config ?

Comment: @RobinThomas when i call this command from root project , show me installed packages:

├── @aws-sdk/client-dynamodb@3.395.0
└─┬ @aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb@3.395.0
  └── @aws-sdk/client-dynamodb@3.395.0 deduped

Comment: @Krystian Possible to share a github repo with all your code?

Comment: @RobinThomas i resolved my problem. Noticed next js compilator show me additional error:  Module not found 'aws-crt'. After installing 'aws-crt' package, problem gone.